# Hyperledger Fabric: Container Size

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm using FabCar project in HyperLedger Fabric (https://github.com/IBM/blockchain-application-using-fabric-java-sdk).

I've been told I need to increase the container size in order to store more transactions, but I don't know how to do so.

I checked the file docker-compose.yml, but I don't see how to change the size of containers.

Thank you.

Comment: Container size or Block size? In order to increase the number of transactions, you need to increase the block size.

Comment: How can that be done?

Comment: If you are spinning up the network, then you can change it beforehand from the configtx.yaml file under BatchSize. Otherwise, if you want to change it without shutting down the network you can follow [this](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/config_update.html) tutorial